# Как взаимодействовать компонентам между собой?

Tags: node.js

Пишу проект с использованием express и с применением компонентного подхода.
Имею такую файловую структуру:

```
components
 user
   index.js
   userModel.js
   userRouter.js
 auth
   index.js
   authRouter.js
   authController.js
```

Насколько я понимаю, мои компоненты не должны быть связаны напрямую, т.е будет неправильно в файле authController.js подключить user компонент для того чтоб при авторизации делать проверку на существующего юзера.

Вот код authController:

```
const passport = require('passport')
const VKontakteStrategy = require('passport-vkontakte').Strategy;
const config = require('config')

passport.use(new VKontakteStrategy({
    clientID:     config.get('auth.vk.clientID'),
    clientSecret: config.get('auth.vk.clientSecret'),
    callbackURL:  `${config.get('domain')}/api/web/auth/vkontakte/callback`
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, done) {
      console.log(profile)
    // Зачем мне подключать компоненты друг к другу напрямую?
    User.findOrCreate({ vkontakteId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));

module.exports = passport
```

Вопрос - как в таком случае я должен связывать эти 2 компонента?

Answer (score 0):

Можно связывать с помощью `let user = require('../user');` Контроллеры как раз и используют для связывания логики моделей и вьюх

Comment: Я как раз и задал этот вопрос потому что не хочу так делать, а хочу разделить компоненты, чтоб они не зависели друг от друга

Comment: Можно создать сервис (Папку Services) и связать эти компоненты там как вариант.